# Using sympy dsolve for simple harmonic motion returns the incorrect solution

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, ode

So i tried to use sympy's dsolve function to solve the very simple case of simple harmonic motion i.e.:

[image]

I did this like so:

```
w = sympy.symbols('ω', real = True, positive=True, nonzero=True)
t = sympy.symbols('t', real = True)
x = sympy.symbols('x')

eq = sympy.diff(sympy.diff(x(t), t), t) + w**2*x

sympy.pprint(sympy.dsolve(eq, x(t)))
```

When I do I get the following solution:

[image]

Instead of [image] or [image] as I expected.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined the d.e. properly. It should be

```
eq = sympy.diff(sympy.diff(x(t), t), t) + w**2*x(t)
```

Note that you can use the more readable `.diff` method

```
eq = x(t).diff(t,2) + w**2*x(t)
```

Comment: How do I extract the solution on it's own so that I can manipulate it? I can't seem to isolate the equation for the solution for x.

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist Let `sol` be the output of the `sympy.dsolve`. `sol` is a sympy Equality object. Use `sol.args[1]` in order to extract the right hand side of the equality. `

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist `sol.rhs` does the same thing and is probably more clear.